# How to configure Startup class in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

I have read [Working with multiple environments](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) and about the [Startup](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/startup.html) class.

> When an ASP.NET Core application starts, the Startup class is used to
>   bootstrap the application, load its configuration settings, etc.
>   (learn more about ASP.NET startup). However, if a class exists named
>   Startup{EnvironmentName} (for example StartupDevelopment), and the
>   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable matches that name, then
>   that Startup class is used instead. Thus, you could configure Startup
>   for development, but have a separate StartupProduction that would be
>   used when the app is run in production. Or vice versa.

So I have 3 startup classes `StartupDevelopment`, `StartupStaging` and `StartupProduction` and my `Program.cs` is configured as below

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<StartupDevelopment>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Note that `.UseStartup<StartupDevelopment>()` is configured for `StartupDevelopment`.

Now in `Staging` and `Production` I would set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` accordingly . However How Asp.Net core would know to use `StartupStaging` or `StartupProduction` since its hardcoded to `StartupDevelopment`?

Comment: Does this `Startup{ENVIRONMENT}.cs` pattern still work? They removed it from their github repository... https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/commit/8c8771f2b765d5a665a2d3639d60888876e3fda4#diff-1b381ac5136edcd1392a3cce02697697

Comment: Apparently it does! I couldn't find an example of it anywhere. I read through the source code to find my answer.

Comment: I would create private `ConfigureDevelopment`, `ConfigureStaging` and `ConfigureProduction` methods and use it conditional in main `Configure` method.

Answer (score 4):

There is [an `IWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(string assemblyName)` extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/93130dd4a1b6ffb7dd0257870563649dad8b67d5/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L50) that you can use to load the correct `Startup{ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}` class. Once that's defined, [here is the algorithm](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/0a7cf6b5a0d090fe085a16e56eb8c8931d31e073/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/StartupLoader.cs#L66) that tries to find the right class.

If you don't want to hardcode the assembly name, you can fetch it programmatically like so:

```cs
using System.Reflection; // Add this so you can use .GetTypeInfo()

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup(typeof(StartupDevelopment).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name)
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

In order for you to use this convention, all of your `Startup*` classes need to be in the same assembly.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working just by passing assembly name

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup("MyAssemblyName")
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have Startup in a separate assembly that Main, have you statically referenced the assembly in your Main project?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)